# PHP $_SESSION variables are not being passed between pages

Tags: php, session-variables

I am working on a school project where I need my .php pages communicating. I have header.php where I set connection to the database and start the session. In order to start the session only once, I've used this:

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

PHP version is PHP 5.3.10-1 ubuntu3.18 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)

I am trying to pass some $_SESSION variables between pages, but they keep being unset when I try to use them on a page that doesn't set them.
I see many people have complained about this, but I still can't find the solution.

**login-form.php**

```
    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION["login-error"])) {
            echo '<p>'.$_SESSION["login-error"].'</p>';
        }   
    ?>
```

**login.php**

```
 $_SESSION["login-error"]= "Username or password incorrect";
```

There is a code snippet of what is not working for me.
Thanks

Comment: Try adding `session_start();` at the very start of the page ? Is this all the code that you have or is there more to it ?Are you getting any error messages ?

Comment: I have more code, and all the pages include the header. so when I put it at the top I get this message ,,Session has already started"

Comment: You don't need the condition. You can't interact with the session until it's enabled.

Comment: Please post the additional code that you have and indicate what part of the code is not working or throwing any errors.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question

Comment: Are you sure that your server stores the session data properly? I had problems in the past when session files could not be created on the server.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @YasenZhelev I think OP's issue is way more common than that. Most likely coding issue.

Comment: `session_start();` must be inside all pages using sessions.

Comment: session_start() is in all the pages because all the pages include header.php

Comment: @YasenZhelev, what do you mean? This is all done locally on my computer. Not hosting it anywhere

Comment: Did you remove the if around your session_start like @StuartWagner mentioned? session_start needs to be called every time, not just the first time. From php.net: session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one

Comment: so, did you add error reporting and if so, what errors are you getting; if any?

Comment: @TylerMarien, I did remove the i part. Still nothing. And I am not getting any errors.

Comment: Please check 'session.save_handler' in the output of phpinfo() function. Also check your 'session save path' by echoing session_save_path() function outcome. Lets check (just in case) your session settings.

Comment: session.save_handler says files files;        session.save_path says /var/lib/php5 /var/lib/php5

Comment: What are your permissions on /var/lib/php5? Do you have any session files in it when you run session_start()?

Comment: Uhh, are you trying to use sessions with the CLI? I'm like 95% sure that won't work.

Comment: @Sammitch, with the cli, yes. What should I do?

Comment: And @Yasen Yhelev, I have changed the permisions on /var/lib/php5 and I have two files in it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

In your function file put this

```
function is_session_started()
{
    if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
        if ( version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=') ) {
            return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE;
        } else {
            return session_id() === '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Then you can run this in every page you want session started

```
if ( is_session_started() === FALSE ) session_start();
```

With this I think you should be good to go on starting your session across pages. Next is to ensure you set a session to a value. If you are not sure what is unsetting your sessions you can try `var_dump($_SESSION)` at different parts of your code so you be sure at what point it resets then know how to deal with it.

Comment: What error? I hope you `var_dump($_SESSION);` or you can try `echo '<pre>',print_r($_SESSION, true),'</pre>';`

Comment: Echoing it works, but still no SESSION variables get saved at all between pages

Answer (score 0):

The variables are probable not set, because you haven't activate the session variables with session_start().

`session_id() == ''` is not a correct conditional . Use instead:

```
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start();}
```

if you have session started then you can set a session variable

```
  if (!isset($_SESSION["login-error"])) { $_SESSION["login-error"]= "Username or password incorrect";}
```

Before you call  $_SESSION["login-error"], type `session_start()`, just for testing, to find when the session signal is missing. You said

*PHP $_SESSION variables are not being passed between pages*

session_start() and SESSION variables needs to be included at the beginning of EVERY page or at the place where SESSION variables are being called (through a common file, bootstrap, config or sth) at the beginning of EVERY page. ie the command to read those data from the server is needed.

Comment: No, the session has started, I can get the session_id(), but the rest doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since my header.php file included "connection.php" file, I put

```
session_start();
```

at the beginning of connection.php and deleted it from header.php file. Now it works fine. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

PHP sessions rely on components of HTTP, like Cookies and GET variables, which are clearly not available when you're calling a script via the CLI. You could try faking entries in the PHP superglobals, but that is wholly inadvisable. Instead, implement a basic cache yourself.

```
<?php
class MyCache implements ArrayAccess {
    protected $cacheDir, $cacheKey, $cacheFile, $cache;

    public function __construct($cacheDir, $cacheKey) {
        if( ! is_dir($cacheDir) ) { throw new Exception('Cache directory does not exist: '.$cacheDir); }
        $this->cacheDir = $cacheDir;
        $this->cacheKey = $cacheKey;
        $this->cacheFile = $this->cacheDir . md5($this->cacheKey) . '.cache';

        // get the cache if there already is one
        if( file_exists($this->cacheFile) ) {
            $this->cache = unserialize(file_get_contents($this->cacheFile));
        } else {
            $this->cache = [];
        }
    }

    // save the cache when the object is destructed
    public function __destruct() {
        file_put_contents($this->cacheFile, serialize($this->cache));
    }

    // ArrayAccess functions
    public function offsetExists($offset) { return isset($this->cache[$offset]); }
    public function offsetGet($offset) { return $this->cache[$offset]; }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) { $this->cache[$offset] = $value; }
    public function offsetUnset($offset) { unset($this->cache[$offset]); }
}

$username = exec('whoami');
$c = new MyCache('./cache/', $username);

if( isset($c['foo']) ) {
    printf("Foo is: %s\n", $c['foo']);
} else {
    $c['foo'] = md5(rand());
    printf("Set Foo to %s", $c['foo']);
}
```

Example runs:

```
# php cache.php
Set Foo to e4be2bd956fd81f3c78b621c2f4bed47

# php cache.php
Foo is: e4be2bd956fd81f3c78b621c2f4bed47
```

This is pretty much all PHP's sessions do, except a random cache key is generated [aka PHPSESSID] and is set as a cookie, and the cache directory is `session.save_path` from `php.ini`.